# Using boost string algorithm predicate with a bind

Tags: c++, boost

Compiling this example

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int , char** )
{
    vector<string> test;

    test.push_back("xtest2");
    test.push_back("test3");

    ostream_iterator<string> out_it(cout, "\n");

    remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), out_it,     
                   boost::bind(boost::algorithm::starts_with, _1, "x"));
}
```

fails with error

```
no matching function for call to 
‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::arg<1>&, const char [2])’
```

---

**What is wrong with the used `bind`call?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `no matching function for call to 
>   ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::arg<1>&, const char [2])’`

So,... resolve `<unresolved overloaded function type>`:

```
remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), out_it, boost::bind(
     boost::algorithm::starts_with<std::string, std::string>, _1, "x"));
```

Ouput:

```
$ g++ ./test.cpp ./a.exe
test3
```

With a bit more work you can make it less ugly to type. A few variations below:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace my // for alternative styles
{
    static bool starts_with(const std::string& s, const std::string& prefix)
    {
        return boost::algorithm::starts_with(s, prefix);
    }

    struct starts_with_s 
    {
        starts_with_s(const std::string& prefix) : _p(prefix) {}
        bool operator()(const std::string& s) const {
            return boost::algorithm::starts_with(s, _p);
        }
        private: const std::string _p;
    };
}


int main(int , char** )
{
    vector<string> test;

    test.push_back("xtest2");
    test.push_back("test3");

    ostream_iterator<string> out_it(cout, "\n");

    remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), out_it,     
                   boost::bind(boost::algorithm::starts_with<std::string, std::string>, _1, "x"));

    remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), out_it,     
                   boost::bind(my::starts_with, _1, "x"));

    my::starts_with_s pred("x");
    remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), out_it, pred);

    // using c++0x style lambdas
    const std::string prefix = "x";
    remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), out_it, [&prefix](const std::string& s) 
            { return boost::algorithm::starts_with(s, prefix); });
}
```

Comment: Aah, the compiler doesn't 'know' which of `starts_with()` two overloads I am talking about, so I got to explicitly tell him using the template arguments. Correct?

Comment: Indeed. Added alternative approaches in case you want to do less (ugly) typing

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this exhaustive answer. I think I'm gonna print it out and pin it above my desktop for future reference :-)

Answer (score -1):

If your compiler supports some C++11, you can use std::bind. In C++11 you would use std::placeholders::_1, so it's probably boost::placeholders::_1 for you.